# C Pointer Basics

Tags: pointers

I have a question about the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 int x, *p = &x, *m = p;
 //p = NULL;
 //*p = NULL;
 printf("%d\n", *m);
 return 0;
}
```

When I set p = NULL and run the program, I get an indeterminate value, but if I set *p = NULL the program will print 0. I'm aware that the distinction between the two lines is setting pointer p = NULL vs the object p points to = NULL, but don't understand why the output is different.

Comment: Small improvement: `int x = 42, *p = &x, ...`  . That gets rid of the 'indeterminate  value'.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code makes `x` an integer, `p` a pointer that points to `x`, and `m` a pointer whose value is that of `p`, which is the address of `x`.

Setting `p` to `NULL` has no effect on the value of `m`, which points to `x`.

Setting `*p` to `NULL` sets `x` to NULL, since `p` points to `x`. Since `m` also points to `x`, setting `x` to NULL causes `*m` (the value of `x`) to be zero.